# Jquery .next(input OR textarea)

Tags: jquery, tabindex

I'm messing with this simple line of code:

```
$(this).next('input').focus();
```

I'd like to get it to select the next `(input OR textarea)`, whichever comes first - how can I do this?

As an alternative, how can I get it to simply focus on the next item in the `tabindex`?

#### Edit

Because the next input/tabindex is not always right after `$(this)`, how can I easily traverse down the list of siblings until I find the next match?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `:input` which selects all input, textarea, select and button elements.

```
$(this).next(':input').focus();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gmcalab/JmwcR/7/)

If the next input is not a sibling, this seems to work...
For this example, click in the textbox with the `id="test"` and it will `focus` on the next `:input` element.

```
<input type="text" value="hello world2"/>
<input type="text" value="hello world3"/>
<div>
    <input type="text" id="test"/>
</div>
<div>
    <div>Hi</div>
</div>
<textarea>found me</textarea>
<input type="text" value="hello world"/>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test').click(function(){
       var c = $(this).parents().nextAll(':input:first').focus();
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/gmcalab/JmwcR/20/)

Comment: .nextAll(':input:first') throws an exception but .nextAll('input:first') seems to work.

Comment: It does **not** throw an exception, look at my working *examples*. You're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 6):

```
$(this).next('input,textarea').focus();
```

But it will only work if the next input/textarea is the sibling immediately following `this`.

Alternatively, you can [use the `:focusable` selector](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-find-next-node-in-focus-order#14737000000749247) from jQuery UI.

[Sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/fxscW/2/) - press enter to focus the next input

You can also [target the first input](http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/fxscW/5/) if no inputs are currently selected by binding to the `document` itself and using `e.target`.